# UnicodeEncodeError while trying to decrypt (pypdf2) file object using python

Tags: python, python-itertools, pypdf

I have been getting the following error in python

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u018f' in
>   position 0: ordinal not in range(256)

While trying to force hack an encrypted pdf using `pypdf2` and `itertools` library files.

Here is my code:

[image]

The weird thing is the code works fine while using a different machine...the python version is 3.6.4 both mine and the machine I tried on.

Things I have tried are:

- I tried running the code on a different machine and it worked fine. Which now makes me think that I had not installed python properly
- I freshly installed python v 3.6.4 and pycharm (latest community version). When that failed I tried anaconda(latest version) which also failed, leading me back to python v 3.6.4

  ```
      import PyPDF2 as pdf
      import itertools

      testFile = pdf.PdfFileReader("File01_Enc.pdf")
      print(testFile.isEncrypted)

      # for n in range(100001):
      #     if n <= 100:
      #         print(n)
      #         t = str(n)
      #         x = testFile.decrypt(t)
      #         if x == 2 or x == 1:
      #             print("The password is: " + str(t)
      #             break
      pwds = itertools.combinations("0123456789", 6)
      for p in pwds:
          print(''.join(p))
          x = testFile.decrypt(''.join(str(p)))
          if x > 0:
              print("The password is: " + ''.join(str(p)))
              break
  ```

Comment: Please post your actual code instead of an image of the code.

Comment: I have just added the code.... still could not solve the problem..

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you find the solution?

Comment: Nope... I still think about this bug 3 years later... Please tell me if you find it